# React not updating JSON feed on re-render

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm attempting to build a small React app that pulls baseball scores from a JSON feed. The JSON feed gets updated on the server by a cronjob to get the latest results every minute.

When I view my react app initially, I get the most up to date scores. I set an interval to render the ReactDOM every minute as well. The `console.log` fires properly but the values from the JSON feed aren't updated. If I reload the page, I can see the information update (for instance it was stuck saying End of 4th Inning when in reality it was into the 5th).

Here is my `index.jsx`

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var MLBScores = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      hometeam: '',
      homescore: '',
      awayteam: '',
      awayscore: '',
      status: 'Pre-game',
      inning: '1',
      inningState: 'Top'
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {

    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.feed, function(result) {

    var scoreFeed = result.data,
        status  = scoreFeed.games.game[4].status.status,
        inning  = scoreFeed.games.game[4].status.inning,
        inningState  = scoreFeed.games.game[4].status.inning_state;

    if( scoreFeed.games.game[4].linescore ){
        var homeScore = scoreFeed.games.game[4].linescore.r.home;
      var awayScore = scoreFeed.games.game[4].linescore.r.away;
    }

      this.setState({
        hometeam: scoreFeed.games.game[4].home_team_name,
        homescore: homeScore,
        awayteam: scoreFeed.games.game[4].away_team_name,
        awayscore: awayScore,
        status: status,
        inning: inning,
        inningState: inningState
      });

    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.hometeam} {this.state.homescore} vs. { this.state.awayteam} {this.state.awayscore}
        <hr />
        {this.state.status} {this.state.inningState} {this.state.inning}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

function render(){
  ReactDOM.render( < MLBScores feed= "http://198.199.92.64/src/client/app/mlb-scoreboard.json" / > ,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
}

setInterval(function(){
  console.log('Scores were rendered.')
  render();
}, 60000);
render();
```

I'm pretty new to React so maybe I'm missing something simple. Any help would be appreciated. You can view the app in real time if you wish [here](http://198.199.92.64/src/client/) - but be aware that the game I'm currently pinging may end and the situation is kind of thrown out the window. Thanks!

Comment: Any particular reason, why you are invoking ReactDOM.render in a setInterval?

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli I want to make sure that the scores on the page are updated without page refresh, since the JSON file is updated every minute. I based it off of how this tutorial talks about updating with render: http://buildwithreact.com/article/updating-with-react-render

Comment: I see. There are other, subjectively better ways of doing it in my opinion. You can move the setInterval logic into the component which you want to get updated. What happens with ReactDOM.render is that, if there are other components which don't need to be refreshed, they end up being "re-evaluated" as well, which is not desirable. Instead, try using setInterval within componentWillMount/DidMount.

Comment: For the first render componentWillMount gets fired. For the subsequent renders you need to use componentWillReceiveProps. That is the issue here. http://jsbin.com/guqegoriwi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @bhargavponnapalli So inside `componentWillReceiveProps` do I need to do all the same code thats inside of `componentWillMount` to get the same result? EDIT: fixed component name

Comment: You can use either DID/WILL mount, the results are not too far off. You will have to include an lifecycle function "componentWillReceiveProps" and handle the new changes and manipulate state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only take a guess from here, since the feed link is unreachable. This should work. Give it a try and let me know.

You need a componentWillReceiveProps function to handle subsequent renders.

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var MLBScores = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      hometeam: '',
      homescore: '',
      awayteam: '',
      awayscore: '',
      status: 'Pre-game',
      inning: '1',
      inningState: 'Top'
    };
  },
  updateUI(props){

      this.serverRequest = $.get(props.feed, function(result) {

    var scoreFeed = result.data,
        status  = scoreFeed.games.game[4].status.status,
        inning  = scoreFeed.games.game[4].status.inning,
        inningState  = scoreFeed.games.game[4].status.inning_state;

    if( scoreFeed.games.game[4].linescore ){
        var homeScore = scoreFeed.games.game[4].linescore.r.home;
      var awayScore = scoreFeed.games.game[4].linescore.r.away;
    }

      this.setState({
        hometeam: scoreFeed.games.game[4].home_team_name,
        homescore: homeScore,
        awayteam: scoreFeed.games.game[4].away_team_name,
        awayscore: awayScore,
        status: status,
        inning: inning,
        inningState: inningState
      });

    }.bind(this));

  },


  componentDidMount: function() {
     this.updateUI(this.props);

  },

  componentWillReceiveProps : function(newProps){
     this.updateUI(newProps);
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.hometeam} {this.state.homescore} vs. { this.state.awayteam} {this.state.awayscore}
        <hr />
        {this.state.status} {this.state.inningState} {this.state.inning}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

function render(){
  ReactDOM.render( < MLBScores feed= "http://198.199.92.64/src/client/app/mlb-scoreboard.json"/>,
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
}

setInterval(function(){
  console.log('Scores were rendered.')
  render();
}, 60000);
render();
```

Comment: I updated the feed to use a game that is currently in progress, for what its worth.

Comment: a current game id is [7].. I will take a look at your code and see how that works. Thanks!

Comment: Edit: fixed a token error issue in function 'render'.

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you so much for putting me in the right direction and taking the time to help.